# How would I do a vanilla JS equivalent of querying multiple selectors with pseudoclasses?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this function:

```
function populate(selector, snippet, location) {
    var OGsnippet = $('snippet#' + snippet).children().clone().appendTo(selector);
}
```

It gets called like this: `populate('section#main articles article:not(".ad")', 'socmed-articles');` or `populate('section div.articles.news article:not(".ad")', 'socmed-articles');`

I'm trying to convert it to vanilla javascript. I have tried:

```
function populate(selector, snippet, location) {
    var snippet = (document.querySelector('snippet#' + snippet).children)[0].cloneNode(true); //printing snippet yields a span with a class socmed-articles
    document.querySelector(selector).append(snippet);
}
```

But I get `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'section#main articles article:not(".ad")' is not a valid selector`

Comment: `section#main` is adding specificity for no gain. IDs are unique, so the `section` prefix is unneeded.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector `:not` doesn't accept the `"`, they need to be removed to use that selector.

```js
document.querySelector('section#main articles article:not(.ad)');
```